# PDO query encoding with MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding, pdo

I have terrible problem getting me sick :) Here is my simple example of my problem:

```
$driver="SQL Server; TDS_Version=7.2; Port=1433";
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver=$driver;Server=$server;Database=$database;charset=utf-8;Uid=$username;Pwd=$password;");
$query="select * from table where f_name like '%aleš%'";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

I have problem with encoding of czech names (aleš). However this query should return some results, it won't. When I do same query with name witch doesn't contain any czech-specific letter (petr), it works perfectly.

I've found some comment on MS-website, that mssql server accept only ucs-2 encoded vartext queries. I've tried that somehow as well, but without luck. Any ideas? Thank you very much! (Sorry - this is my 1st time with mssql).

Answer (score 0):

I have approximately the same setup as you (SQL Server, PDO) and had the same problem.
Now I send the form data to PHP via jQuery AJAX call and when I construct the GET string I do 'encodeURIComponent' and it encodes the special characters (ščžýáí) correctly.

```
var formdata = $('#test_form').serializeArray();
req = '';
$.each(formdata, function(i,element){
    req += element.name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(element.value) + "&";
});
```